# backbone events triggered when binding

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

I need to bind click events to certain amount of special divs, which divs should be binded are only known at runtime
so I was thinking simply set a class for all these special divs and bind them in "events", but then click on one of these divs would trigger all divs to fire
then I tried to use variables in events, but these variables are only know at runtime, so it turns out they are undefined when binding events
now I am using jQuery to bind the events inside Backbone at runtime, but whenever I initialize the view, the event fires right away

```
var RoomNumber = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#roomColumn' + this.roomNumber),
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.user = this.options.user;
        this.roomNumber = this.options.roomNumber;
        this.render();
        //$('#roomNumber'+this.roomNumber).on('click', this.enterBooking());
    },
    render: function () {
        $(this.el).append("<div class = 'roomNumber' id  = 'roomNumber" + this.roomNumber + "'>" + this.roomNumber + "</div>");
    },
    enterBooking: function () {
        var slideForm = new SlideForm({
            user: this.user,
            roomNumber: this.roomNumber,
            state: 'book',
            singleSchedule: new Schedule()
        });
    }
});
```

Would anyone kindly explain why these would happen? And how can I bind events to a dynamically generated divs?

(I know I probably should not have used a backbone view like this..but it's part of requirements )

Comment: How are you generating the views? Could you include the code which  calls `new RoomNumber()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is having two problems:

1. Answering to your point, events are triggered when binding because you are calling the event handler while binding.

   `$('#roomNumber'+this.roomNumber).on('click', this.enterBooking());` 
   should be
   `$('#roomNumber'+this.roomNumber).on('click', this.enterBooking);`
    Notice the function call braces.
2. The way you have set the el is wrong

   `el: $('#roomColumn' + this.roomNumber),`
    In backbone, `el` property of the view gets set before the `initialize` method gets called. This would mean that backbone would try to find for an element `$('#roomColumnundefined')` which is not expected. Instead, you can pass the `el` element as an option to the view

   ```
       var roomNumber = 3;
       var view = new RoomNumber({
           roomNumber:roomNumber,
           el:$('#roomColumn' + roomNumber)
       });
   ```

Comment: those were indeed the problems, no one was answering so I eventaully figured it out myself. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
......
//Pseudo code
render: function () {
    $(this.el).append("<div class = 'roomNumber' id  = 'roomNumber" + this.roomNumber + "'>" + this.roomNumber + "</div>");

    //you can dynamic set up events like this:
    this.events["click #roomNumber"+this.roomNumber] = "enterBooking";
    this.delegateEvents(this.events);

},
......
```